# How can I detect when the user gets a View and do something after getting this position on React Native?

Tags: react-native, animation, view, position, scrollview

I have a ScrollView with some Views inside it, but I want to start an animation when the user gets to specific View and after it starts my animation.

Example:

```
<ScrollView style={{ width: DeviceWidth, height: DeviceWidth * 0.5 }}>

   {/* When user position scroll is here, 
       is where I want to start the animation, 
       not since the page is loaded */}

   <View style={{
         width: DeviceWidth * 0.4,
         height: DeviceWidth * 0.4,
         resizeMode: "contain",
      }}>
      <ProgressBarAnimated
          width={barWidth}
          value={65}
          backgroundColor="#F68D29"
          height={40}
          barAnimationDuration={6000}
      />
   </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `ScrollView` you can instead use a `FlatList`, this gives you a lot more support for the type of indexing you're trying to do.

To detect when a user reaches a specific point you can use `onViewableItemsChanged` and the define which viewable items need to be on screen in order to trigger your animation.

`FlatLists` also support a number of build in animations like `scrollToEnd` or `ScrollToIndex` which may be helpful.